# ASP.net VB search engine

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, web-services, foreach

I have a search engine that is supposed to search through descriptions of products and then will display something with a list of products that have whichever word(s) or phrase the user was looking for. I haven't made any kind of list for the products that use the description though.

I just need to figure out why my SELECT statement isn't doing anything. It's either that or the For Each loop.

This is what I have:

```
 Public Function GetDescriptions(ByVal prefixText As String, ByVal count As Integer) As String()
    Dim MarketingSql As String = "Select MarketingID, MarketingType, MarketingData FROM Marketing WHERE MarketingType = 2 AND MarketingData LIKE '%" & prefixText & "%'"
    Dim sqlConn As New SqlConnection
    sqlConn.Open()
    Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand(MarketingSql, sqlConn)
    Dim myReader As SqlDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
    Dim myTable As New DataTable
    myTable.TableName = "DescriptionSearch"
    myTable.Load(myReader)
    sqlConn.Close()
    Dim items As String() = New String(myTable.Rows.Count - 1) {}
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For Each dr As DataRow In myTable.Rows
        items.SetValue(dr("MarketingData").ToString(), i)
        i += 1
    Next
    Return items
End Function


<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
<script type="text/javascript">
function AutoCompleteClientMethod(source, eventArgs) {
    var value = eventArgs.get_value();
    window.location = ("/Product/Default.aspx?id=" + value)
} 
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="body" Runat="Server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    <Services>
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="DescriptionSearch.asmx" />
    </Services>
</asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:TextBox ID="Search" runat="server" AutoComplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="Search" ServicePath="~/DescriptionSearch.asmx" ServiceMethod="GetDescriptions" MinimumPrefixLength="1" CompletionSetCount="255" EnableCaching="true" OnClientItemSelected="AutoCompleteClientMethod">
    </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how the WebService was updated for the project. It works just fine now.

```vb
 <WebMethod()> _
Public Function GetDescriptions(ByVal prefixText As String, ByVal count As Integer)
As String()
    Dim MarketingSql As String = "Select DISTINCT p.ProductID, p.ProductName 
FROM Product p 
INNER JOIN Marketing m ON p.ProductID = m.ProductID 
INNER JOIN Picklist k ON k.PicklistID = m.MarketingData 
WHERE m.MarketingTypeID = 2 AND k.Data LIKE '%' & @prefixText & '%' 
ORDER BY p.ProductName ASC"
    Using sqlConn As New SqlConnection
      (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
      ("LocalSqlServer").ConnectionString)
    sqlConn.Open()
    Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand(MarketingSql, sqlConn)
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@prefixText", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = prefixText
    Dim myReader As SqlDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
    Dim myTable As New DataTable
    myTable.TableName = "DescriptionSearch"
    myTable.Load(myReader)
    sqlConn.Close()
    Dim items As String() = New String(myTable.Rows.Count - 1) {}
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For Each dr As DataRow In myTable.Rows
        Dim id As String = dr("ProductID").ToString()
        Dim name As String = dr("ProductName").ToString()
        Dim item As String = AjaxControlToolkit.AutoCompleteExtender.CreateAutoCompleteItem(name, id)
        items.SetValue(item, i)
        i += 1
    Next
    Return items
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you @JoelCoehoorn for helping me with injection problems.

Answer (score 3):

Right off the bat I see three *big* problems with your code:

1. As you say, your code is vulnerable to sql injection. You put that live, and anyone who cares to try completely owns your database. It's not even hard. The "get it working first" strategy is a completely backwards and wrong way to approach this.  Too often code like that makes it to production.
2. You're searching lengthy text columns using the LIKE operator.  That will suck the life out of your database performance.  This is a great spot for a full-text index and the [CONTAINS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) function. It will be night and day with regards to search times.
3. You don't always close your database connection.  If an exception is thrown, you'll leak open connection objects, and this can eventually result in an effective denial of service attack on your database, originating from your own application.  Database connections **must always** be encased in a try/finally block.

And that's just the tip of the iceberg, gleaned from merely skimming. I haven't even started reading deeply into the code yet.

---

Here's an update (late, I know), based on the self-accepted answer to fix the sql injection issue:

```vb
 <WebMethod()> _
Public Function GetDescriptions(ByVal prefixText As String, ByVal count As Integer)
As List(Of String)
    Dim MarketingSql As String = "Select DISTINCT p.ProductID, p.ProductName 
      FROM Product p 
      INNER JOIN Marketing m ON p.ProductID = m.ProductID 
      INNER JOIN Picklist k ON k.PicklistID = m.MarketingData 
      WHERE m.MarketingTypeID = 2 AND k.Data LIKE '%' + @prefixText + '%' 
      ORDER BY p.ProductName ASC"

    Using sqlConn As New SqlConnection
      (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
      ("LocalSqlServer").ConnectionString), _
          myCommand As New SqlCommand(MarketingSql, sqlConn)

        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@prefixText", SqlDbTypes.VarChar, 50).Value = prefixText
        sqlConn.Open()
        Using myReader As SqlDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
            While myReader.Read()
                Dim id As String = myReader("ProductID").ToString()
                Dim name As String = myReader("ProductName").ToString()
                items.Add(AjaxControlToolkit.AutoCompleteExtender.CreateAutoCompleteItem(name, id))
            End While
         End Using
     End Using
     Return items
End Function
```

Comment: @Nick - just now saw your comment. I went to Harding University.

Comment: @Joel lol he was asking me but I deleted my comments because I was hoping the moderators would delete this post since I had to answer it myself.

Comment: @jlg - that explains it. And looking now at the code in your answer, I see you still have the gaping sql injection vulnerability in there :(

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was trying to put the prefixText in parameters, but I couldn't figure it out. :)

Answer (score -1):

In addition to Joel's comments, you really really need to NEVER put Select statements in your code (Even while testing)... Ever.  Always use Stored Procedures.  Right now all I need to do is read your web.config file (assuming you haven't taken the time to encrypt it), read your connection and I have complete and total access to all your data.

Comment: A parameterized query would also do wonders. And this is a horrible way to learn -- ask your school why you know more than the instructor.

Comment: Stored procedures aren't the only option. Plenty of alternatives, particularly in terms of OR/Ms (like LINQ and NHibernate) work fine without the need for stored procs. As for the issue of more homework now than when you were in school, welcome to the world of technology. You have to be constantly learning new stuff in order to survive.

Comment: Also, feel free to check out the search implementation on my site using LINQ that I describe at http://www.thinqlinq.com/Default/Dynamically-extending-LINQ-queryies-without-building-expression-trees.aspx.

Comment: True, true Jim.  I do apologize to mislead into thinking Stored Procedures were the only other option.  I was just trying to stress not putting the statement in code.  My bad, yo.

Comment: What would be the next step for me though? Since I don't know anything about security, I want to take baby steps here and not overwhelm myself, especially since getting this done is pretty important. By the way this is an internal site that will get used by about 4 people so we aren't too worried about injection at this point in time. I will be more worried when making live sites though since you all pointing out the mistakes!

Comment: There are certain ways to build a site.  First and foremost you think data (as in database design), secondly IS ALWAYS security, then finally you build your site. So do you need a database?  if the answer is yes, then you build it first, otherwise building the UI without a business or data layer is pretty much useless.. Hand in hand with the data is your security.. It's just the proper way to design. Of course there are more steps but these are the most important..